# cannot install install php-gd into centos 7.2 for Intervention Image plugin on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

halo guys. i really frustate for setup Intervention Image on my laravel. 
im using :

- Laravel Framework 5.4.36,
- PHP 7.2.12
- bento/centos7.2
- Vagrant 2.1.1

at first i got this error after setup up "Intervention Image".

```
GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.
```

so i run this commend :

```
sudo yum -y install php-gd
```

but display error :

```
Error: Package: php-gd-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.el7
           Installed: php-common-7.2.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php72)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.2.12-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i also run with this code :

```
sudo yum -y install php-gd --skip-broken
```

but display this error :

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    libX11-1.6.5-2.el7.x86_64 from base
    libX11-common-1.6.5-2.el7.noarch from base
    libXau-1.0.8-2.1.el7.x86_64 from base
    libXpm-3.5.12-1.el7.x86_64 from base
    libjpeg-turbo-1.2.90-6.el7.x86_64 from base
    2:libpng-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64 from base
    libxcb-1.13-1.el7.x86_64 from base
    php-gd-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 from base
    t1lib-5.1.2-14.el7.x86_64 from base
```

i also found another code :

```
sudo yum install php7.2-gd
```

but the result is this :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.buana.web.id
 * epel: epel.mirror.angkasa.id
 * extras: mirror.buana.web.id
 * remi-safe: mirror.xeonbd.com
 * updates: mirror.buana.web.id
No package php7.2-gd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

what should i do. i need to make resize image into Smartphone size and ipad size. so i use "Intervention Image plugin".. is there any solusion for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>        Installed: php-common-7.2.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php72)
> ```

So you need to enable the **remi-php72** repository and install the **php-gd** package from it.

As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
yum install php-gd
```

Comment: thank you very much. God bless you. but after i successed install php-gd. i still have error "GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation."

Comment: Restart your webserver and.or fpm service.

Comment: ah sorry i forgot to restart the apache. thank you verymuch

Answer (score 2):

assuming repository `remi-php72` is still enabled:

- [php72-php-gd-7.2.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/php72-php-gd-7.2.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html)
- [php72-php-gd-7.2.13-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/php72-php-gd-7.2.13-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html)

which can be  installed with:

```
sudo yum install php72-gd
```

Comment: Thanks I used `sudo yum install php70-gd` on my ec2 instance with php version 7.0.33 , it worked

Answer (score -1):

Its seems simple installation issue, I would suggest to reinstall the PHP, php-devl and then try to install php-gd on a fresh system.